# Grouping a list of lists as a set in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a dataset with 1 ID column, a column containing lists of strings and 2 sets of scores.

I need to group by the list of strings, but the issue is that the list of strings is unordered.
for instance:

| ID | LIST | SCORE1 | SCORE2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c("a","b") | 10 | 100 |
| 2 | c("b","a") | 20 | 500 |
| 3 | "a" | 10 | 200 |
| 4 | "c" | 10 | 300 |
| 5 | c("b","a","c") | 20 | 300 |

I want to group by the LIST column, to add up scores, lets say. How would I group it in a way that it considers each list a set, c("a","b") and c("b","a") should be considered the same thing.

The output I'm trying to get would be something like

| LIST | SCORE1 | SCORE2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c("a","b") | 30 | 600 |
| "a" | 10 | 200 |
| "c" | 10 | 300 |
| c("b","a","c") | 20 | 300 |

Should I not be using strings for something like this? How would dplyr be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unnest` the data, `sort` the `list` values, `group_by` them and `sum` the `Score` values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unnest(list) %>%
  group_by(ID, Score1, Score2) %>%
  summarise(list = list(sort(list)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  group_by(list) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Score'), sum, na.rm = TRUE))

#     list Score1 Score2
#1    a, b     30    600
#2       a     10    200
#3       c     10    300
#4 a, b, c     20    300
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Score1 = c(10, 20, 10, 10, 20), Score2 = c(100, 
500, 200, 300, 300), list = list(c("a", "b"), c("b", "a"), "a", 
    "c", c("b", "a", "c"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class ="data.frame")
```

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly! I just had a secondary question. What would I do differently if I wanted to aggregate/summarise the two scores using different functions? Is it possible to do things like sample scores (for example instead of adding 100 and 500 I randomly sample one of the two)?

Comment: Yes, you can change the last line to `summarise(across(starts_with('Score'), sample, 1))`